# Working with a huge state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with handling state in a React application. For some background: The application mostly renders a big table with lots of data that is then editable. The data comes from a single source as a big list of objects (actually it’s a more complicated hierachy but let’s keep it simple for this purpose), and should be kept as it is. Users can then partially change the data in the big table, and ultimately save their changes.

Since the data comes from a single source, I’m [thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) and store the data as the table state and pass everything necessary down to the individual components. So a row gets only the row data as a prop, and the cell gets only the cell data as a prop. For the update process at cell level, I then use an inverse data flow to call an update method on the table that updates the state for the updated cell:

```
change (rowIndex, cellIndex, value) {
    this.state.data[rowIndex][cellIndex] = value;
    this.forceUpdate();
}
```

This works pretty fine in theory. However, I have **a lot** data; the table easily contains about 1000 rows with multiple columns. This is not a problem directly: it takes a bit time for the browser to render the table, but once it’s there, it can work with it pretty well. Also, React doesn’t have a problem with that data amount either.

But the problem is that changing *a single cell* essentially triggers a rerender of the whole table. Even if the DOM is only changed for a single cell as a result, all the render methods are executed with most of them not doing anything (because the change only happened in a single cell).

My current solution is to implement [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) for the row component and perform a deep check on all mutable values to avoid a rerender at row and cell level. But this feels very messy as it’s not only very verbose but also very dependent on the data structure.

So I’m not really sure how to tackle this better. I’m currently thinking about moving the state into the rows, and as such also the mutation functionality, and have the table component query the rows for changes on demand. Alternatively I could also move the whole data out of the table, and only work with identifiers the rows then use to query the data from a central store that provides the data and also offers mutation functions. This would be possible because the whole data is loaded once on page load, and then only mutated by the user.

I’m really unsure on how to handle this situation. I’m even thinking of dropping React for this, and rendering everything as static HTML with a custom JavaScript module on top that fetches the data on-demand from the actual input elements when a save is requested. Is there a way to solve this in a good way?

In case you want to play around with this situation, I have a running example [on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNZXyX?editors=001). As you type into one of the many input fields, you will notice a lag that comes from React calling all the `render` functions without really changing anything in the DOM.

Comment: @crush I’m not interested in table/grid solutions that use virtualization as that prevents browser search capabilities. Also, the actual application I’m working on has multiple requirements that require a custom implementation (I reviewed many existing grid solutions before coming to that conclusion). The example on CodePen is just a very stripped down example just focusing on the data size problem.

Comment: @crush But the state doesn’t really belong in the rows/cells since it’s one coherent set of data and the outer component (the table) is also responsible for sending it back to the server etc. And I really want to avoid duplicating state and having the `onChange` affect both the local state (to trigger a local rerender) and a nonlocal state (to keep track of the new values). The state and data should only be owned by a single component to ensure data consistency.

Comment: @crush Please submit your idea as an answer and explain it thoroughly. It’s difficult for me to follow what you’re suggesting there. Also, the data displayed in the (editable) table *is* the data/state that I have and need to work with. Feel free to use my CodePen as a basis for your explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at PureRenderingMixin and shouldComponentUpdate documentation

I made some changes to your code so you don't modify state directly so shouldComponentUpdate can properly compare the props to determine if a rerender is required. The code here is a bit messy and I hacked it together really fast but hopefully it gives a good idea of how it could be implemented.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYXbaL?editors=001

Table

```
  change (rowIndex, cellIndex, value) {
    this.state.data[rowIndex][cellIndex] = value;
    var newData = this.state.data.map((row, idx) => {
      if(idx != rowIndex){
        return this.state.data[idx]
      } else {
        var newRow = this.state.data[idx].map((colVal, idx) =>{
          return idx == cellIndex ? value : colVal
        })
        return newRow
      }
    });
```

Row

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
    return this.props.cells != nextProps.cells;
  }
```

Comment: That’s a very good idea which keeps the `shouldComponentUpdate` very simple and independent from the data structure too. I could probably abstract that away, so I can have some `patchState` function which just updates single rows like that. I like this :) I’m going to try this tomorrow on my full code to see how well it performs. Thanks!